# deployment template is missing when attempting to deploy

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-logic-apps

**How do we ensure that there is a deployment template?**

I'd like to deploy my logic app, and the steps that I've followed are:

[image]

[image]

**Where is the template?**

Comment: Maybe this link will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal

Answer (score 2):

Have you removed the whole "$schema" line or removed the part of the "$schema" line in your .json file. If the line of "$schema" missed, it may result in this issue you mentioned in this ticket.
[you may refer to this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqi9X.png)